# How do I create a table with more than one column from a single list?

Tags: visualforce

I have code such as the following:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!myContacts}" var="c" columns="3">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:outputText value="{!c.FirstName}"/><br />
        <apex:outputText value="{!c.LastName}"/><br />
        <apex:outputText value="{!c.Email}"/><br />
    </apex:column>
    <br />
</apex:dataTable>
```

This will display something like:

```
John
Smith
js@example.com

Sue
Jones
sjo@example.com

Joe
Mack
jma@example.com

Jane
Doe
jd@example.com
```

I want to display myList across N (e.g., 3, 4, etc.) different columns, so that the result is like the following (N=3 in this case).  Note that the number of columns is not the same as the number of items on the list.

```
John              Sue                Joe
Smith             Jones              Mack
js@example.com    sjo@example.com    jma@example.com

Jane
Doe
jd@example.com
```

How can this be done?  Preferably there's just some attribute of `apex:dataTable` or other apex component tag staring me in the face that I'm missing.

Note that specifying `columns="3"` on the `apex:dataTable` has no effect -- still just one column.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the number of columns static or dynamic?

Comment: @MikeChale - I was thinking dynamic to have a more general solution, but static is acceptable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you need to use the datatable tag for some other reason, this could be done with `<apex:repeat>` and html `table` tags:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!myContacts}" var="c" />
    <td>
        <apex:outputText value="{!c.FirstName}"/><br />
        <apex:outputText value="{!c.LastName}"/><br />
        <apex:outputText value="{!c.Email}"/><br />
    </td>
    </apex:repeat>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  Worked perfectly.  I had a a less than ideal situation where this absolutely had to be in an apex:pageBlockSectionItem so I just had to nest this inside of an apex:outputPanel inside of the apex:pageBlockSectionItem

Answer (score 3):

The description in the developers guide doesn't make sense to me based on how it functions, but the **rowspan** attribute on **apex:column** gets this done:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!myContacts}" var="c">
    <apex:column rowspan="{!myContacts.size}">
        <apex:outputText value="{!c.FirstName}" /><br />
        <apex:outputText value="{!c.LastName}"/><br />
        <apex:outputText value="{!c.Email}"/><br />
    </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions I've seen:

- On the developer boards: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Adding-Columns-to-Datatable-dynamically/td-p/297337
- In a Salesforce guide: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_dataTable.htm

The Salesforce guide they point out a property, columns, that sets the number of columns in the table. The developer board shows a solution with a custom controller that sets the number of columns dynamically.